# Integration of $\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{x-x^2}}$dx

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, improper-integrals, riemann-integration

I have recently been trying out some questions on improper integrals and in an intermediate step,  I was supposed to find the value of I where

$$I=\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{x-x^2}}dx$$

I tried using $x = \sin^2\theta$ then the answer is $\arcsin$$\sqrt{x}$

But on trying to evaluate the integral using the method of completing the squares, Answer is coming out to be different.

Please help!

Comment: Can you show your work via each method? It would make it easier to see any flaws (or, who knows, maybe your answers are equivalent in some way).

Comment: Different ? How so ?

Answer (score 2):

Completing the square you can write $$\int {dx \over \sqrt{{1 \over 4}-(x-{1 \over 2})^2}}=2\int {dx \over \sqrt{1-(2x-1)^2}}$$
substitute $u=2x-1, du=2dx$ and then it's trivial to see that your integral is $\arcsin(u)+C=arcsin(2x-1)+C$.
Substituiting $x=\sin(\theta)$ in the original integral left me with a $\sin^{{-1 \over 2}}(\theta)$ term which doesn't seem easy to handle.

Comment: I substituted x=$\sin^2\theta$ and got $\arcsin(\sqrt{x})$ which doesn't look difficult either.N also you too got two different answers.Isn't integration unique upto an additive constant?

Comment: I got only one answer.  Your substitution (sorry for getting it wrong) leads to $2\arcsin(\sqrt(x))+C$. Those solutions are indeed the same, the only thing that changes is the constant term. Can you prove this?

Comment: Yes..But that was my question itself!

Comment: @Gitika have you tried using the arcsine addition formula or the complex definition of the arcsine function? Those should work

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try and compare with my completion of the square.
$$\int\frac{1}{\frac{1}{4}-(x-\frac{1}{2})^2}dx$$

From here, simply substitute $u=x-\frac{1}{2}$ and then $u=\frac{\sin(\alpha)}{2}$ to end up with
$$\arcsin(2x-1)$$